# Train/fit a Linear Regression in sklearn with only one feature/variable

Tags: scikit-learn, regression

So I am understanding lasso regression and I don't understand why it needs two input values to predict another value when it's just a 2 dimensional regression.

It says in the documentation that

```
clf.fit([[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
```

which I don't understand. Why is it `[0,0]` or `[1,1]` and not just `[0]` or `[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

means that you have 3 samples/observations and each is characterised by 2 features/variables (2 dimensional).

### Indeed, you could have these 3 samples with only 1 features/variables and still be able to fit a model.

**Example using 1 feature.**

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import linear_model

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :1]  # we only take the feature
y = iris.target

clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.1)

clf.fit(X,y)

print(clf.coef_)
print(clf.intercept_)
```

Comment: I tried using 1 feature but then the prediction model just follows a straight line parallel to the x-axis even though I was using Lasso regression. How to fix this problem?